# How do I run multiple functions until one returns?

Tags: lua, coroutine

I have two infinite loops  ( while true do ) and I need the program to continue running after one of those functions returns something. BUT when the first function returns, the second is still running.
How do I do that with coroutines in lua?

Comment: So, there are functions inside the infinite loops or are you waiting for one of the infinite loops to break so the other one can break?

Comment: I have two functions that each contains an infinite loop. I want to run them simultaniously and the program to continue when ONE of these functions break.

Answer (score 0):

As Oleg said, they do not actually run at once. They simply take turns running.

I believe you're looking for something like this (?):

```
active = true
coroutine.resume(coroutine.create(function()
        while active do
            print("Hello")
            if (condition) then
                active = false --Since the loops only run if active is true, this effectively breaks both loops
                break
            end
        coroutine.yield()
        end
end))

    active = true
coroutine.resume(coroutine.create(function()
        while active do
            print("Hi!")
            if (condition) then
                active = false --Since the loops only run if active is true, this effectively breaks both loops
                break
            end
        coroutine.yield()
        end
end))
```

**What's happening here:** We switch control from thread to thread, allowing 1 loop each time, and instead of while true do we're running while active is true. So by setting active to false inside a loop, we break the other loop as well.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, they don't "run simultaneously" - Lua (and pretty much most other "multitasking" systems) always runs only one piece of code. So your infinite "manager" loop will call first coroutine, wait until it yields or ends, then call second, waits for it and then resumes first one and continues this process until the end.

Plan logic in both your coroutines so they periodically `yield` from time to time with some reasonable period according to your task. When one of them ends successfully you simply drop the other without resuming.